# django - Way to avoid custom manager for specific queries

Tags: django, django-orm, django-managers

I have the following issue: I am working on a grown project which uses the pattern of overriding the `get_queryset()` method in the manager.

```
# Model declaration
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = MyModelManager()


# Manager declaration
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyModelManager, self).get_queryset().exclude(is_visible=False)
```

This causes some of the records to become basically invisible when you use the django ORM.

I need now in certain edge cases to use the base `get_queryset()` method and NOT to use the custom one.

I could clean up and change all the code but it would be a lot of work.

**So my question: Is there a way to make a query like this `MyModel.objects.all()` and avoid using the custom manager method?**

Hope I made my point clear enough.

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Just add another manager.

Comment: My use case is a tool to anonymize the database. I call a management command which needs to find all records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add *multiple* managers to your model. For example:

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyModelManager, self).get_queryset().exclude(is_visible=False)


class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …

    objects = MyModelManager()
    all_objects = models.Manager()
```

If you then need *all* the objects, you can thus access these with `MyModel.all_objects.all()`.

Comment: I thought about this but hopefully I thought there is a more generic solution I could build into this tool: https://pypi.org/project/django-scrubber/
So I solve the problem for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another custom manager which does not override get_queryset() method and it would be better if you use different name then common *objects* name that you have to define custom manager only once.